# How to executeScript when new page is loaded

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to build an extension that is downloading an image that has the URL in the meta tag of the current page, when the extension button is clicked.
Unfortunately, I have some issues figuring out how to get the URL of the image each time when I navigate to a new page.

With other words, my extension is partially working. It is always downloading the image from the first page I visit instead of downloading a new image when I navigate from the first page to a page that is linked to the first one.

Here is my code:
*manifest.json*

```json
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Image downloader",
  "description": "This extension alows you to download your images",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_title": "Download Picture"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "activeTab",
    "downloads"
  ]
}
```

*popup.html*

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Getting Started Extension's Popup</title>
    <style>
      body {
        font-family: "Segoe UI", "Lucida Grande", Tahoma, sans-serif;
        font-size: 100%;
      }
      #status {
        white-space: pre;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        overflow: hidden;
        max-width: 400px;
      }
    </style>

    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="status"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

*popup.js*

```js
/**
 *Download images
 *
 */
function getCurrentTabUrl(callback) {
    var queryInfo = {
        active: true,
        currentWindow: true
    };
    chrome.tabs.query(queryInfo, function (tabs) {
        var tab = tabs[0];
        var url = tab.url;
        console.assert(typeof url == 'string', 'tab.url should be a string');

        callback(url);
    });
}

function renderStatus(statusText) {
    document.getElementById('status').textContent = statusText;
}

function getImage() {
    var imgUrl = "";
    var url = "";
    var title;

    getCurrentTabUrl(function (url) {
        if (url.substring(0, 13) != 'https://page1') {
            renderStatus('Please navigate to page1 ');
        } else {
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
                file: 'script.js'
            },
            function (result) {
                imgUrl = result[0];
                var filenametimestamp = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
                if (imgUrl == null) {
                    renderStatus('Not Found... ');
                } else {
                    renderStatus('Downloading... ');
                    console.log('URL: ' + imgUrl);
                    chrome.downloads.download({
                        url: imgUrl,
                        filename: filenametimestamp + ".jpg"
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });
};

window.onload = function () {
    console.log('onload');
    getImage();
};
```

*script.js*

```js
var picUrl
    //location.reload();
var metas = document.getElementsByTagName('meta');
for (var i = 0; i < metas.length; i++) {
    if (metas[i].getAttribute("property") == "og:image") {
        picUrl = metas[i].getAttribute("content");
        imgUrl = picUrl;
        i = metas.length + 1;
    }
}
picUrl;
```

I tried `window.onclik` but the same problem happens.

Here is a screen-recording of the issue (click for full size recording which is stored off-site due to being too large to upload here):

[image: screen-recording of the issue]

Comment: To actually provide a solution, we are going to need to know in more detail what sequence of events you actually desire to happen with respect to what the user interaction is with the extension and Chrome and when *exactly* you expect the image to be downloaded.

Comment: From your code, I don't understand why you have a popup.  There does not appear to be any user interaction in the popup and no information provided to the user.  What is the purpose of the popup instead of just actions when the `action_button` is clicked (without displaying the popup)?

Comment: I expect the url stored in the meta with property "og:image" of the current tab to be passed to the chrome.downloads.download when the user is clicking the chrome extension icon.  The pop-up is used for displaying information to the user like: renderStatus('Downloading... ');

Comment: my expected result partially happens. the meta with property "og:image" is passed to chrome.downloads but it is not the meta of the current page from the tab. it is the meta of the first page I opened in that tab

Comment: You say you want to download the image from the current page when the UI button is clicked. You say that is working.  Then you say that you are expecting it to download when you navigate to a new page. Did you click the UI button once you are on this new page?

Comment: yes, I clicked it, and the image from the previous page is downloaded

Comment: Do the URLs shown in the [Browser Console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Console) (Ctrl-Shift-J, or Cmd-Shift-J on OSX) from your `console.log('URL: ' + imgUrl);` match the file being downloaded, or what you were expecting to download? Are you *sure* that there is not a `<meta property="og:image">` in the page with the URL you are actually downloading? BTW: [`break;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break) is the normal way to terminate a loop early.

Comment: Yes the URLs sow in the browser console and the one being downloaded is from the previous page. Here is a screen-recording of the issue: [link](http://g.recordit.co/xvBi8DeaY8.gif)

Comment: I was expecting to download the picture from the current page: forest, but the picture from the previous pge was downloaded instead

Answer (score 0):

I investigated this issue more and I found out that the browser extension works well on other sites. so it must be a limitation of the site I was initially testing it.
Thank you for your help!